# Pyomo objective function and constraint declaration

Tags: python, csv, pyomo, gurobi

I'm currently doing my senior thesis and I am doing an optimization problem in both GAMS and Pyomo. I am supposed to obtain the same solution of the objective function for both programs, however, they differ. I was wondering if someone could help me check the constraint and objective function declaration and tell me where I fail in Pyomo. My model is abstract, so I have to upload CSV documents and solve it using Gurobi.

OBJECTIVE FUNCTION CORRECT RESULT IN PYOMO: 448250.630754

```
from pyomo.environ import * 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = AbstractModel('TFG_MMP_v2.0_July_2023')

#SET DECLARATION
m.G = Set()
m.p = Set()
m.s = Set() 
m.n = Set()
m.t = Set()
m.h = Set()
m.hf = Set()

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename= 'g.csv', set= m.G)
data.load(filename= 'p.csv', set= m.p)
data.load(filename= 's.csv', set= m.s)
data.load(filename= 'n.csv', set= m.n)
data.load(filename= 't.csv', set= m.t)
data.load(filename= 'h.csv', set= m.h)
data.load(filename= 'hf.csv', set= m.hf)

#PARAMETER AND SCALAR DECLARATION
m.e = 480
m.CO2rate = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.alfa = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.beta = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.gamma = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.f = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.o = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.qmax = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.qmin = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.bmax = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.wmax = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.w0 = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.wmin = Param(m.G,within = NonNegativeReals)
m.k = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)
m.rend = Param(m.G, within = NonNegativeReals)

# Read CSV file into pandas DataFrame and convert to Pyomo parameter
param_data = pd.read_csv('Data_duration_demand1.csv', header=0, index_col=[0, 1, 2])
m.a = Param(m.n, m.s, m.p, initialize=param_data['a'].to_dict(), within = NonNegativeReals)
m.d = Param(m.n, m.s, m.p, initialize=param_data['d'].to_dict(), within = NonNegativeReals)

param_data2 = pd.read_csv('Data_inflows1.csv', header=0, index_col=[0, 1])
m.i = Param(m.h, m.p, initialize=param_data2['i'].to_dict(), within = NonNegativeReals)


param_data3 = pd.read_csv('Data_qred1.csv', header=0, index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3])
m.qred = Param(m.t, m.n, m.s, m.p, initialize=param_data3['qred'].to_dict(), within= NonNegativeReals)

data.load(filename="Data_generators1.csv", param=(m.CO2rate, m.alfa , m.beta , m.gamma , m.f , m.o , m.qmax , m.qmin , m.bmax , m.wmax , m.w0 , m.wmin , m.k , m.rend))

#VARIABLE DECLARATION
m.u = Var(m.t, m.s, m.p,within= Binary) #u(t,s,p) Decision to connect generator g
m.y = Var(m.t,m.s, m.p, within= Binary)#y(t,s,p) Start up decision for generator g
m.z = Var(m.t, m.s, m.p, within= Binary)#z(t,s,p) Shut down decision for generator g 
m.qt = Var(m.t, m.n, m.s, m.p, within= NonNegativeReals) #q(t,n,s,p) Net power delivered by thermal generator t [GW]
m.qh = Var(m.h, m.n, m.s, m.p, within= NonNegativeReals) #q(h,n,s,p) Net power delivered by hydraulic generator h [GW]
m.b = Var(m.h, m.n, m.s, m.p, within= NonNegativeReals) #b(h,n,s,p)Gross power consumed by pumping-storage plant [GW]
m.w = Var(m.h, m.p, within= NonNegativeReals) #w(h,p) Hydroelectric energy in the reservoir of the plant [GWh]

#OBJECTIVE RULE
def obj_rule (m):
    return sum((m.f[t]*(m.gamma[t]*m.y[t,s,p] + sum((m.a[n, s, p] * (m.alfa[t] * m.qt[t,n,s,p] / m.k [t] + m.beta[t] * m.u[t, s, p])) for n in m.n))  + 
        sum((m.a [n, s, p]* m.o[t] * m.qt[t, n, s, p] / m.k[t]) for n in m.n )) for t in m.t for p in m.p for s in m.s)

m.obj = Objective(rule= obj_rule, sense= minimize)

#DECLARATION OF CONSTRAINTS
    #Demand balance and marginal cost
def Demand_Bal_rule(m,n,s,p): 
    return sum((m.qt[t,n,s,p]) for t in m.t) + sum((m.qh[h,n,s,p] - m.b[h,n,s,p]) for h in m.h) ==  m.d[n,s,p]

m.Demand_Bal = Constraint(m.n, m.s, m.p, rule= Demand_Bal_rule)

    #Upper thermal limit 
def Upper_Thermal_rule(m,t,n,s,p):
    return m.qt[t,n,s,p] <= m.u[t,s,p] * m.k[t] * m.qmax[t]

m.Upper_Thermal = Constraint(m.t, m.n, m.s, m.p, rule= Upper_Thermal_rule)
    #Upper hydro constraints
def Upper_Hydro_rule(m,h,n,s,p):
    return m.qh[h,n,s,p] <= m.k[h] * m.qmax[h]

m.Upper_Hydro = Constraint(m.h, m.n, m.s, m.p, rule= Upper_Hydro_rule)
    #Maximum Capacity limits for pumped storage
def Upper_Pumping_rule(m,h,n,s,p):
    return m.b[h,n,s,p] <= m.k[h] * m.bmax[h]

m.Upper_Pumping_Hydro = Constraint(m.h, m.n, m.s, m.p, rule= Upper_Pumping_rule)
    #Lower thermal limit
def Lower_Thermal_rule(m,t,n,s,p):
    return m.qt[t,n,s,p] >= m.u[t,s,p] * m.k[t] * m.qmin[t]

m.Lower_Thermal = Constraint(m.t, m.n, m.s, m.p, rule= Lower_Thermal_rule)
    #Energy balance in an equivalent reservoir
def E_Bal_rule(m,h,p):
    if p == m.p.first() and h == 'HYDRO_RES':
         return m.w[h,p] + sum(m.a[n,s,p] * (m.qh[h,n,s,p]/m.k[h] - m.rend[h] * m.b[h,n,s,p]) for n in m.n for s in m.s) <= 1200 + m.i[h,p]
    elif p == m.p.first():
         return m.w[h,p] + sum(m.a[n,s,p] * (m.qh[h,n,s,p]/m.k[h] - m.rend[h] * m.b[h,n,s,p]) for n in m.n for s in m.s) <= m.i[h,p]
    else:
        return m.w[h,p] + sum(m.a[n,s,p] * (m.qh[h,n,s,p]/m.k[h] - m.rend[h] * m.b[h,n,s,p]) for n in m.n for s in m.s) <= m.w[h,int(p) - 1] + m.i[h,p]

m.E_Bal = Constraint(m.h, m.p, rule= E_Bal_rule)
    #Upper limit equivalent energy stored in reservoir
def Upper_W_rule(m,h,p):
    return m.w[h,p] <= m.wmax[h]

m.Upper_W = Constraint(m.h, m.p, rule = Upper_W_rule)
    #Lower limit equivalent energy stored in basin
def Lower_W_rule(m,h,p):
    return m.w[h,p] >= m.wmin[h]

m.Lower_W = Constraint(m.h, m.p, rule = Lower_W_rule)
    #Minimum operating hours for thermal group during the year
def Min_H_t_rule(m,t):
    return sum((m.a[n,s,p] * m.qt[t,n,s,p]) for n in m.n for s in m.s for p in m.p) >= m.k[t] * m.qmax[t] * m.e

m.Min_H_t = Constraint(m.t, rule = Min_H_t_rule)


 #Minimum operating hours for hidraulic group during the year
def Min_H_h_rule(m,h):
    return sum((m.a[n,s,p] * m.qh[h,n,s,p]) for n in m.n for s in m.s for p in m.p) >= m.k[h] * m.qmax[h] * m.e

m.Min_H_h = Constraint(m.h, rule = Min_H_h_rule)

    #Minimum production to accommodate grid constraints
def Min_Grid_rule(m,t,n,s,p):
    return m.qt[t,n,s,p] >= m.qred[t,n,s,p]

m.Min_Grid = Constraint(m.t, m.n, m.s, m.p, rule = Min_Grid_rule)

    #Constraint for intra-period changes
def Intrap_changes_rule(m,t,p):
    return m.u[t,'fes',p] - m.u[t,'lab',p] == m.y[t,'fes',p] - m.z[t,'fes',p]

m.Intrap_changes = Constraint(m.t, m.p, rule= Intrap_changes_rule)
    
    #Constraint for inter-period transition
def Intrap_transitions_rule(m,t,p):
    if p == m.p.first():
        return Constraint.Skip
    else:
        return  m.u[t,'lab',p] - m.u[t,'fes',int(p) - 1] == m.y[t,'lab',p] - m.z[t,'lab',p]

m.Intrap_transitions = Constraint(m.t, m.p, rule= Intrap_transitions_rule)

#SOLVER
instance = m.create_instance(data)
solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')
results = solver.solve(instance)

#OBJECTIVE RESULT
print('OBJ=',round(value(instance.obj),2))
```

ECUATION DECLARATION

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFw7R.png)

CSV DATA:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/143jmri1kPDzJx0VraqQO9N3oeSMKoGrI?usp=sharing

RESULT OBTAINED: 525017.77

I don't know exactly what is failing. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: GITHUB LINK IN CASE IT IS EASIER TO READ FOR ANYONE: https://github.com/juanraposo2000/PYOMO_MMP

Comment: first I would check the solver status to ensure it is 'optimal'.  I don't see you doing that.  Do you have access to the solved variables in GAMS?  This wouldn't be too big to do a by-hand comparison of a few of the key flow variables for deltas.  Perhaps also make a small test case with just 2 time periods, some "1's" for coefficients that you can check by hand to ensure what you think you coded is correct